# Nuxt generate vuetify styles issue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I created a project with `Nuxt.js` and Vuetify. In nuxt Dev mode everything is ok, but when I run nuxt generate, the result styles are messed up; Font sizes are too small and there is a strange background color, but I didn't give dose styles. Some vuetify default styles like border-radius are missing too.

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

changing nuxt target: 'static' in nuxt.config.js and disabling vuetify treeshaking with treeShake: false fixed the problem. I suggest to make nuxt extractCSS: true